# Twilio - Making call to phone number from Asp.net C# web application

Tags: c#-4.0, twilio

I am trying to code making a call to phone number from web application using c# without MVC. using the trial url, able to make a call and listening the demo voice . Now i want to go live/ test with my voice like taking in the web application using system/laptop mic/speaker. What to pass in the URL parameter. Iam using the

```
var call = CallResource.Create(
            record: true,
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("xxx-xxx-xxxx"),
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("xxx-xxx-xxxx"),
            url: new Uri("https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Hi Vimaan, it's great that you've managed to get the quick start working using the demo URL.

If you want to go further with this, then I recommend diving deeper into the documentation to find out more.

I'd first start with this tutorial on [how to respond to incoming calls in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-csharp). Once you've got the idea of responding with TwiML to an incoming call, you can then use those URLs in your outbound calls too.

Make sure you read up about [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) itself, without it you won't get very far with voice calls.

If you want to connect two calls together, so that you can speak to someone else over a Twilio call, check out this tutorial on [call forwarding with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-csharp-mvc).

Finally, if making a call from your laptop is the goal you'll want to read up on [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) and there's a [quickstart available](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart) for that and a [full on tutorial for C# ASP.NET MVC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-calls-csharp-mvc) too.

Have a look through that documentation and good luck!

Comment: Hi  Philnash,  I have a similar requirement where I can make a direct call to any phone number and talk (human call not recorded or programmed human to human call) using my existing ASP.NET MVC application.  Can you please guide me step by step how I can achieve this with Twilio ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Hi @MahmadKhoja, that is absolutely possible. Have you checked out any of the links in the above answer?